# Free tool for automating GUI testing of a Windows Forms application and a Web application

Tags: ruby, winforms, automation, ironruby, watir

Is there a way to automate GUI testing of a Windows Forms application and a web application (HTML) using free tools?

For example, Ruby + Rspec + Watir work great for web UI testing.
IronRuby + Rspec can work for winforms apps.
Does anybody know a tool that can do both, WinForms and Web?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine them"?  Why do you think they won't work together?

Comment: Watir and IronRuby don't work together so far, and I'm not sure how to access winforms from Ruby.

Comment: So your question is actually "does IronRuby work with Watir?"?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to automate testing of a winforms application and a web application using one tool.

I mentioned IronRuby and Watir as an example. I'll correct the question. It's likely confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) for GUI testing of such applications. 
The donwloadable bundle includes a record-and-play tool, but it's more advisable to use button names/ids rather than recorded (X,Y) coordinates in order to minimize dependency on changes and screen resolution.

Comment: I've tried to use AutoIt with Ruby. 
AutoIt is good for automating routing tasks, but not for development automated functional tests.

It's difficult to debug scripts even using it separately, without Ruby. It takes quite a long time to write a working script.

When I tried to use AutoIt from Ruby, in most cases AutoIt functions returned wrong return values. It makes writing tests even more complicated and cumbersome.

So I gave up this idea and looking for another ways.